# Drop a foreign key constraint based on output of a complex select statement in informix?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, informix

I'm using INFORMIX database.

I have added forign key to a table without giving it a name e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE myreport ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (rid) REFERENCES report(id), ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES user(id);
```

I want to drop its forign key constraints on the basis of output of a select statement as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE myreport DROP CONSTRAINT (
   SELECT b.constrname
       FROM
           systables a, sysconstraints b, sysindexes c, syscolumns d
       WHERE
           a.tabname = 'myreport' AND (d.colname='rid' or d.colname='uid')
       AND
           b.tabid = a.tabid
       AND
           c.idxname = b.idxname
       AND
           d.tabid = a.tabid
       AND
       (
           d.colno = c.part1 or d.colno = c.part2 or d.colno = c.part3 or d.colno = c.part4 or
           d.colno = c.part5 or d.colno = c.part6 or d.colno = c.part7 or d.colno = c.part8 or
           d.colno = c.part9 or d.colno = c.part10 or d.colno = c.part11 or d.colno = c.part12 or
           d.colno = c.part13 or d.colno = c.part14 or d.colno = c.part15 or d.colno = c.part16
       )
);
```

> Which throws a error `201: A syntax error has occurred.`

But when I run it separately it works fine and gives following outputs as follows:

**Select:**

```
SELECT b.constrname
       FROM
           systables a, sysconstraints b, sysindexes c, syscolumns d
       WHERE
           a.tabname = 'myreport' AND (d.colname='rid' or d.colname='uid')
       AND
           b.tabid = a.tabid
       AND
           c.idxname = b.idxname
       AND
           d.tabid = a.tabid
       AND
       (
           d.colno = c.part1 or d.colno = c.part2 or d.colno = c.part3 or d.colno = c.part4 or
           d.colno = c.part5 or d.colno = c.part6 or d.colno = c.part7 or d.colno = c.part8 or
           d.colno = c.part9 or d.colno = c.part10 or d.colno = c.part11 or d.colno = c.part12 or
           d.colno = c.part13 or d.colno = c.part14 or d.colno = c.part15 or d.colno = c.part16
       )
```

Gives:

```
constrname  r169_278
constrname  r169_279
constrname  r169_280
```

**ALTER TABLE:**

```
ALTER TABLE cuicscheduledreports DROP CONSTRAINT (r169_278, r169_279)
```

Shows a success log

> > So I need a set of queries which will do achieve my requirement in dynamic way, since it will be used as migration for db on different system

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

DROP CONSTRAINT does not allow a subquery for the constraint name(s). The constraint names must be named explicitly.

The syntax of DROP CONSTRAINT is documented here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0069.htm

```
DROP CONSTRAINT Clause

                           .-,----------.          
                           V            |          
|--DROP CONSTRAINT--+---+----constraint-+--+---+----------------|
                    '-(-'                  '-)-'
```

Only a comma-separated list of names is allowed, not a subquery.

You must do this task in two steps, as you have discovered.

In the future, you should avoid making up imaginary syntax and expecting it to work. Check the manual to learn the syntax options.

Comment: So can u give me a set of queries which will do it in any no of steps, Because this query is a migration for db on different system

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what migration tool or process you are using.

Comment: There is no migration tool, We write some set of sql files which we execute on db one by one using some scripts, so I need a set of query statement which will execute on different systems and it should drop the constrains

Comment: Okay, then you already have the solution. You posted it in your question above. Do a SELECT to get the names of the constraints, and then use that result to form an ALTER TABLE statement.